# Why does Professor Higgins pull down his hat to cover his eyes at the end of My Fair Lady?

Tags: my-fair-lady

At the end of *My Fair Lady* why does Henry or Professor Higgins pull down his hat and slouch in his chair?

[image: Henry Higgins with hat over his eyes]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [original script](https://thescriptsavant.com/movies/My_Fair_Lady.pdf), Higgins covers his face (*pretending* to be sleeping) because he doesn't want Eliza to see just how ecstatic he is that she's returned to him.

> **Eliza:** *I washed my face and hands before I come, I did.*
>
> (HIGGINS straightens up, face front, joy on HIS face. HE would like to run to HER, but HE obviously doesn’t know how. With contented confort, HE stretches back on the stool, leaning against the desk, and pulls HIS hat down over HIS eyes)
>
> **HIGGINS:** *Eliza? Where the devil are my slippers?*
>
> (ELIZA smiles. The music of "I WANT TO DANCE ALL NIGHT" reaches a crescendo in the orchestra, as the CURTAIN FALLS for
>
> THE END

Comment: Interesting that the phrase “reaches a crescendo” (reaches an increase??) is that old.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - The expression dates back hundreds of years before this was written; https://www.google.com/search?q=%22reaches+a+crescendo%22&tbm=bks&prmd=ivsn&sxsrf=AB5stBiCzHFluj8rsT2O3fVcpGu0f9oiEw:1689266317738&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjwzLK2j4yAAxWETEEAHV4sBFMQpwV6BAgOEBc&biw=412&bih=743&dpr=2.63

Comment: ?  I see only recent books there.

Comment: @AntonSherwood - I see uses from the 1700s at least

Answer (score 4):

### He's covering his face in an attempt to sleep.

This is/was a common method of cutting out the light from your surroundings when trying to take a nap.

Comment: Now that all is right in his world, he can relax.